# Updating JSF Model is not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have the following:

View:

```
<h:form class="form-signin">

<h:inputText id="name" name="name" value="#{userCabinetController.user.name}" required="true" requiredMessage="Поле имя не заполнено" class="form-control" type="name"/>

<h:inputText id="email" name="email" value="#{userCabinetController.user.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите логин (email)" class="form-control" type="email"/>

<h:inputSecret id="password" name="password" value="#{userCabinetController.user.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Введите пароль" class="form-control" type="password"/>

<h:commandButton action="#{userCabinetController.updateUser}" value="Изменить данные" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"/>

</h:form>
```

Controller:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserCabinetController {

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    /**
     * get user instance for further updating
     */
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
    User userFromSession = (User) sessionMap.get("user");
    int userId = userFromSession.getId();
    user = userFacade.finById(userId);
}

private User user;

@Inject
UserFacade userFacade;

public void updateUser() {
    System.out.println(user);
    userFacade.updateUser(user);
}

// getters/setters
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

And Facade:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserFacadeImpl implements UserFacade, Serializable{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        em.merge(user);
    }
   }
```

But when I try to update user instance it gives the same one, i.e. the old instance without giving new values.

How to update user instance? What is wrong?

Comment: if you dont use ajax, the request scope enough for the controller. log in the init method to see. wether it creates a new controller instance? (which package do you import from the RequestScoped annotation?)

Comment: What is the version of jsf you are using ? Please see http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.in/2013/05/jsf22-viewscope-using-cdi.html?m=1 for version issues with Viewscoped

Answer (score 0):

The `UserFacadeImpl.updateUser()` should pass back the updated user object to the controller:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserCabinetController {

  public void updateUser() {
    System.out.println(user);
    user = userFacade.updateUser(user);
  }
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class UserFacadeImpl implements UserFacade, Serializable {

public User updateUser(User user) {
        user = em.merge(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually. It didn't work. The problem is that in the controller, before updating instance System.out.println(user); gives the same values. Seems  like something wrong with view and controller and new values are not passed to the controller.